# "Unable to build EntityManagerFactory" after creating Many to Many rrelationship

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I just created a many to many relationship in my database and my program stopped running. This is the error I get:

```
759 [JavaFX Application Thread] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration  - Processing fk mappings (*ToOne and JoinedSubclass)
767 [JavaFX Application Thread] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration  - Processing extends queue
767 [JavaFX Application Thread] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration  - Processing extends queue
767 [JavaFX Application Thread] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration  - Processing collection mappings
776 [JavaFX Application Thread] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass  - Second pass for collection: gear7.partyrock.model.Atividade.convidados
777 [JavaFX Application Thread] ERROR gear7.partyrock.utils.JPAUtils  - Não conseguiu carregar a EntityManagerFactory: [PersistenceUnit: PartyRockPU] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
```

This is my first Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "convidados")
public class Convidado implements AbstractEntity, Serializable {
...
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.convidado", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Atividade> atividades;
```

This is my second Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "atividades")
public class Atividade implements AbstractEntity, Serializable {
...
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.atividade", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Convidado> convidados;
```

This is my relationship table:

```
@Entity
@AssociationOverrides({
    @AssociationOverride(name ="pk.convidado", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name ="convidado_id")),
    @AssociationOverride(name ="pk.atividade", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name ="atividade_id"))
})
public class ConvidadoAtividade implements Serializable {
    private ConvidadoAtividadePk pk = new ConvidadoAtividadePk();
    private Date dataCheckIn;

    @EmbeddedId
    public ConvidadoAtividadePk getPk() {
        return pk;
    }

    private void setPk(ConvidadoAtividadePk pk) {
        this.pk = pk;
    }

    @Transient
    public Atividade getAtividade() {
        return getPk().getAtividade();
    }

    public void setAtividade(Atividade atv) {
        getPk().setAtividade(atv);
    }

    @Transient
    public Convidado getConvidado() {
        return getPk().getConvidado();
    }

    public void setConvidado(Convidado conv) {
        getPk().setConvidado(conv);
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "dataCheckIn", nullable = false)
    public Date getDataCheckIn() {
        return this.dataCheckIn;
    }

    public void setDataCheckIn(Date dataCheckIn) {
        this.dataCheckIn = dataCheckIn;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;

        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;

        ConvidadoAtividade that = (ConvidadoAtividade) o;

        if (getPk() != null ? !getPk().equals(that.getPk()) : that.getPk() != null)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (getPk() != null ? getPk().hashCode() : 0);
    }
}
```

I have really no idea why it keeps giving me that "Second pass for collection" message is showing up and why it is unable to build the PU. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace exception?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you put `@OneToMany` on both sides. You need on one side (the "one" side) to put `@OneToMany`, and on the other (the "many" side) to put `@ManyToOne`.

Or, If there's indeed a list on both side, you maybe need to use the `@ManyToMany` annotation.